# Inverting a matrix with specific structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $T$ denote a generic row vector $1 \times n$. By *generic* I mean I'm gonna construct a matrix with lots of $T$'s and each one can represent a different row vector. In the same way, let $D$ be a generic matrix $m \times mn$ given by
$$D = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
T & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & T & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & T
\end{array}
\right].$$

Finally, let $C_i$, for $i=1\ldots m$, be a generic matrix $n \times mn$ given by
$$C_i = \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & \ldots & T & \ldots & 0\\
0 & \ldots & T & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \ldots & T & \ldots & 0
\end{array}
\right].$$

All $T$'s are at the $i$th "column" (it is in fact a block column) of $C_i$.

Write $-\textbf{1}$ for the $m \times m$ matrix composed by $-1$ in each entry. I want to know under what conditions the following matrix is invertible.
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
-\textbf{1} & D & D & D\\
\hline\\
0 & 0 & C_1 & C_1\\
0 & 0 & C_2 & C_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & C_m & C_m\\
\hline\\
0 & C_1 & 0 & C_1\\
0 & C_2 & 0 & C_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & C_m & 0 & C_m\\
\hline\\
0 & C_1 & C_1 & 0\\ 
0 & C_2 & C_2 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & C_m & C_m & 0\\
\end{array}
\right].$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never invertible: the first $m$-columns are identical, the matrices $C_i$ do not have full rank. No chance.

Comment: All matrices $C_i, D$ and row vectors $T$ are supposed to be distinct. I used the same notation just to keep it simple. I can't see how there are lot of repeated rows.
Anyway, you are right about the first $m$ columns. I failed to see this simple fact. Thanks.